# How to produce histograms from large table set of mammals. new to coding

Tags: r

I am trying to create a histogram for the geographic range size of mammals.

I have data columns with geographic range size and different mammal names.

```
hist1 = hist(x = dat1$Range_Area_km2, 
             breaks = 100, 
             col = "blue", 
             border = "green", 
             main = "Geographic Range Size of Mammals", # add a title
             xlab = "Km2", # change axis labels
             ylab = "Frequency", 
             xlim = c(0, 65000000), # change the axis limits
             ylim = c(0, 200))
```

I am expecting a histogram of geographic range size of all mammals.

```
 structure(list(rownames = 1:20, MSW05_Binomial = c("Melomys_rubicola", 
"Peromyscus_dickeyi", "Mogera_uchidai", "Pteropus_pelewensis", 
"Mysateles_garridoi", "Neotoma_anthonyi", "Microtus_breweri", 
"Hypsugo_lophurus", "Neotoma_martinensis", "Pteropus_howensis", 
"Crocidura_dhofarensis", "Mesocapromys_angelcabrerai", "Ochotona_gaoligongensis", 
"Myotis_abei", "Rhynchomys_isarogensis", "Calomyscus_tsolovi", 
"Monodelphis_unistriata", "Geocapromys_ingrahami", "Hesperoptenus_gaskelli", 
"Neotoma_bunkeri"), MSW05_Order = c("Rodentia", "Rodentia", "Soricomorpha", 
"Chiroptera", "Rodentia", "Rodentia", "Rodentia", "Chiroptera", 
"Rodentia", "Chiroptera", "Soricomorpha", "Rodentia", "Lagomorpha", 
"Chiroptera", "Rodentia", "Rodentia", "Didelphimorphia", "Rodentia", 
"Chiroptera", "Rodentia"), MSW05_Family = c("Muridae", "Cricetidae", 
"Talpidae", "Pteropodidae", "Capromyidae", "Cricetidae", "Cricetidae", 
"Vespertilionidae", "Cricetidae", "Pteropodidae", "Soricidae", 
"Capromyidae", "Ochotonidae", "Vespertilionidae", "Muridae", 
"Calomyscidae", "Didelphidae", "Capromyidae", "Vespertilionidae", 
"Cricetidae"), AdultBodyMass_g = c(100, 28.6, NA, NA, NA, 195.4, 
NA, NA, 240.16, 232.92, NA, NA, NA, NA, 122.29, NA, 55.3, 733.52, 
NA, 375), LitterSize = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.5, NA, NA, 
0.98, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.04, NA, NA), Range_Area_km2 = c(0.000187, 
0.00725, 0.03, 0.06, 0.49, 0.66, 1.85, 2.7, 2.8, 3.16, 3.52, 
3.55, 4.89, 5.11, 5.28, 6.78, 6.86, 8.36, 8.89, 9.15), Precip_Mean_mm = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 290, NA, NA, 7, 111, 195, 52, 331, 18, 
107, NA, 237, NA), Temp_Mean_degC = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 24.6, NA, NA, 21.1, 24.6, 11.3, -0.9, 25.2, 17.1, 17.9, NA, 
20.6, NA), ActivityCycle = c(NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), DietBreadth = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
2L, NA, NA), HabitatBreadth = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA), Terrestriality = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 
2L, 2L, NA), TrophicLevel = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: can you do `dput(head(dat1, 20))` and paste the result as code in your question? This will help people reproduce your problem.